# What exactly are ancestors in DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, ancestor

I am new to graph theory and confused with ancestors definition in DAG(or in general graph).

```
For example in the following DAG

1--->2--->3<---4<---5
```

If I start DFS from 1 vertex first then path covered is 1--2--3. Then next if I start DFS from vertex 5,
then the path covered is 5--4. Vertex 3 is not visited again.  So visited order is 1 2 3 5 4.
What about the ancestors of 3. Are they only 1,2 or 4,5 also ?
what about ancestor Ancestor of 4. Is it only 5 or 1,2 also as they were also visited before visiting 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *ancestors* of a vertex *v* in a DAG is the set of all vertices *v'* != *v* such that *v* is reachable from *v'*. So in your example, the ancestors of 3 would be 1, 2, 4 and 5.

Of course it's different if you are just looking at a particular *path*: so the ancestors of 3 in the path 1->2->3 would just be 1 and 2.

Comment: Youi are right. In the definition of ancestors, 'v is reachable from v' is important. So  ancestors of 3 can be 1, 2, 4 and 5.